Kavana for סֶּֽלָה
It is clear from this question that the word Selah isn't well understood. We have several wildly different definitions, and some of them have no associated Kavana.
This becomes a halachic problem because we need to concentrate on the meaning of the words when we pray, and it comes up a lot, even in Berachot, such as קדושת השם and מודים of the Amidah.
So, when it comes to davening, how should we decide which opinion to use for Selah, especially if it's a machloket? If we pick the opinion that says it is just a vocal device such as a raise in voice or a pause, then does that actually count as a Kavana?
I guess I am asking the same question but halachically, in terms of Kavana. I hope therefore it isn't voted to be closed. Answers should explain why they chose which definition, and, if it isn't a simple definition, a guide on how to integrate that into one's Kavana during Tefilla.

I like the approach of Rav S.R. Hirsch in Tehillim (3:3) that it's telling the reader to mediate once more upon that which has just been said, or upon its consequences that have not been mentioned explicitly.

@DannySchoemann I like that too. Could I bother you to write it up, for everyone's benefit?

For individual prayers, a synchronic approach may make more sense where you care less what it meant way back when and more what it meant to the person who composed the prayer you are saying.

@DoubleAA Interesting. Makes sense, but do we have that information, and is it subject to machlokes?

@Rabbi I doubt we have it conclusivly, but even if the translation in the Septuagint is what a Psalmist meant, the translation in the Targum (widely known by later Jews) is much more likely what the author of whatever later prayer text meant.

"If we pick the opinion that says it is just a vocal device such as a raise in voice or a pause, then does that actually count as a Kavana?" Why wouldn't it? (On a personal note, I think of all three meanings mentioned here when I daven).

The crux of the question seems to be how to choose which definition to use when one is uncertain which of multiple definitions to choose. I believe the Rambam (Commentary on Mishnah Orlah 3:2) tells us that the correct way to choose is to go by the definition given by the earliest authority:

הסיט (זו המלה) הוא שתות הזרת וראיתי בזו המלה פירושים הרבה וזכרתי מהם פחות שבשעורים לחומרא ונתחזק אצלי זה הפירוש מפני שהוא פירוש הקדמונים והקדמון הוא יותר חכם בלשון מן האחרון

In this case that is the definition of the Targumim (Yonasan Ben Uziel to Chabakuk and unknown to Tehillim) which is לעלמין, or "forever".
I believe this is also the generally accepted translation given in schools etc.

The Septuagint predates those Targumin by a couple centuries

@DoubleAA The Septuagint is not part of our Mesorah. The one done by our Sages only covered the Pentateuch, and we did not preserve it. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Os0NWGbrC70

The rambam didn't say find the oldest thing "in your mesorah" for matters of language. Indeed the Talmud tells many stories of asking non Jews to translate obscure words.

@DoubleAA The Septuagint is not earlier than the Targum in this case. In addition, it is not a reliable source. Even the editors of the King James Bible didn't rely on it. The Talmud has examples of learning the definition of words from speech on non-Jews, but I don't know of any cases of asking them.

According to Wikipedia, Yonatan Ben Uziel's teacher Hillel died in 10ce while the Septuagint is from ~200bce, so I don't know why you say the targum is earlier in this case. I also don't know why you bring up asking vs hearing or why that matters. I also don't know why it matters what King James thought. Just declaring anything older than the source you want "unreliable" without justification is hardly what the rambam intended.

@DoubleAA The Septuagint on the Torah is from around 200 BCE, but on the other books it's later. How much later is subject to dispute, and N.T. may then well be correct that it's coeval with Yonasan ben Uziel or at least with Hillel. Not to mention that the Gemara says that his translation is "from the mouths of Chaggai, Zechariah and Malachi," who predate the Septuagint on Torah by a century or more.

cc @N.T. (There is, by the way, at least one example of a Gaon asking a non-Jew for his understanding of a posuk - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/125530/18471 - though indeed not in the Gemara, as far as I know.)

@Meir Wikipedia says "The remaining books were presumably translated in the 2nd century BCE." "The translation process of the Septuagint... completed by 132 BCE" Not sure where you're getting 10 CE here, but at least let's all appreciate the irony that someone trying to defend the [in his mind] "traditional" position is accusing the bible academics of dating an early biblical work too early.

@DoubleAA See the video I linked to. The Septuagint was a general term for any Greek translation of the "Old Testament". It was done by anonymous people of unknown reliability, mainly Christians with an agenda. The very fact that these translations are called the Septuagint when in fact they have no relation to the seventy Sages shows their unreliability. And the current version is based on Origen, who was third century CE.

You vs wikipedia

@DoubleAA I'm actually quoting Rabbi Tovia Singer, in the video. And Wikipedia agrees that the current Septuagint is from Origen, if you read the whole article.

@N.T. Pointing at "current" editions is irrelevant for this. We have ancient Jewish ones that probably precede Jesus himself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Minor_Prophets_Scroll_from_Nahal_Hever Rabbi Singer likes to attack missionaries but this is an issue that has nothing to do with theology so we can safely leave the polemics aside. Talk about people with an agenda.

@DoubleAA If you really read Wikipedia you would know that the Septuagint extant today is not older than the Targumim. The one you cited is just a few scraps of parchment, not a full translation. It has historical value in showing that translations existed, but it only includes actual translations on a handful of verses. And obviously it matters who wrote them. The Rambam doesn't need to tell you not to blindly trust every Tom Dick and Harry who wrote something.

Also the Torah today is no earlier than the Masoretes in Aleppo since that's the manuscripts we base ourselves on. Come on now. If you really were honest you'd simply say there this earlier tradition which disagrees and while it may have theoretically been corrupted by later copyists there's no reason to think they'd do so, just like there's no reason to think our Targum has been corrupted. And yes the rambam actually does believe in trusting Tom Dick and Harry, as well as the random servant in Rebbi's house. Again that's literally the whole point.

Btw the one I cited includes parts of Havakuk. I haven't checked if it has our verse, but maybe someone who has time can. That's what should be involved in making the claim you've made here.
